# convert the data series into array using for loop python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, sequence

I have a data series of around 15000 sequences. I need to change the data into

X = [ first 3750 series], y = [11th 375 data]

X2= [2nd 3750 series],    y2=[12th 375 data]

How to code it in python using for loop?

Comment: can you show what your working with and what you are expecting

Comment: To say your question "lacks details or clarity" is a bit of an understatement - I don't have the first idea what you're talink about...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as following:

```
 lst = [i for i in range(15000)]
 x = lst[:3750]
 y = lst[3750:4125]
 x2 = lst[7500:11250]
 y2 = lst[11250:11625]
```